# objectFromJSONString crash when launching app that uses Simperium

Tags: ios, simperium

I'm getting a `JSON` crash when I try to launch an app that uses the Simperium framework:

```
[__NSCFString objectFromJSONString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c561a0
```

It happens immediately. Am I missing an external dependency? It looks like a `JSONKit` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simperium uses JSONKit internally. You'll need to add `-ObjC` to your Other Linker Flags (found under Build Settings in your target).

Comment: I F**KING LOVE YOU!!! Working on an App using Philips Hue SDK and was searching for hours why my app is crashing. You're the best :)