# getting error when calling objectFromJSONString using JSONKit

Tags: ios, sigabrt, jsonkit

I use the following code to create a dictionary based on a JSON string received from the server. (I have downloaded JSONKit and embedded it into the project). The code below returns a legal JSON string from the server (parsed well on Android) but crashes when I try to convert it to a dictionary.

```
- (IBAction)submit
{
bool useSSL = true;
char *c_url="http://(rest of URL)";


NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s" , c_url];
url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%s", url, self.label.text, "/keys"];
NSString * response = [self getDataFrom:url];


NSDictionary *dict = [response objectFromJSONString]; //generates SIGABRT!!
NSLog(@"%@",dict); 

NSString *success = [dict valueForKey:@"success"];

} 



- (NSString *) getDataFrom:(NSString *)url{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

if([responseCode statusCode] != 200){
    NSLog(@"Error getting %@, HTTP status code %i", url, [responseCode statusCode]);
    return nil;
}

return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:oResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
}
```

THANKS,
Simon

Comment: Can you try put NSLog(@"%@",response); before `NSDictionary *dict = [response objectFromJSONString];` and see what is the output.

Comment: instead of using the 3rd party json library, y dont u use the nsjsonserialization(above iOS5)....here is the link....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization

Comment: Seems like your JSON response is incorrect

Comment: I build for 4 and up so I cannot use the native library.
The output of the NSLOG:
{"key":"1234","address":"http:\/\/www.mishkanothamada.com","success":"true","type":"keys","method":"keys"}

Comment: What error do you see in Xcode when your app crashes?

Comment: In which line does your app crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705427/jsonkit-parsing-error).
Answer says: "Figured it out... I had JSONKIt.h included in the project but for some weird reason, JSONKit.m was not included in the 'Compile Sources' under 'Build Phases' - once I added it manually it started working fine."